# How to use spring Page without spring data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi i'm using below code for find article using spring with plain hibernate.

```
public List<Article>  getArticles(int currPosition, int pageSize) {
        Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Article.class);
        c.addOrder(Order.desc("createdDate"));
        c.setFirstResult(currPosition);
        c.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        List<Article> result = c.list();
        return result;
    }
```

i'm not using spring data in my project now, So how can i use `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` with my project.

```
Page<Person> persons = personService.findAllPageable(new PageRequest(evalPage, evalPageSize));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pageable#getSize](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html#getPageSize--) to set `maxResults`, [Pageable#getOffset](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html#getOffset--) for `setFirstResult` and [Pageable#getSort](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html#getSort--) to obtain sorting parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use pagerequest :

```
public class PagePersons implements Serializable {
     private List<Persons> persons ;
     private int page ;
     private int numberPersons ;
     private int totalPersons ;
     private int totalPage ;

 //getters setters
}
```

and call your persons repository for exemple

```
   public PagePersons getPagePersons(int codePerson, int page, int size) {
    Page<Person> Persons= personRepository.getPagePersons(codePerson, new PageRequest(page, size));

   PagePersons pagePersons =new PagePersons();
   pagePersons.setPersons(persons.getContent());
   pagePersons.setPage(page);
   pagePersons.setNumbrePersonss(persons.getNumberOfElements());
   pagePersons.setTotalPage(persons.getTotalPages());
   pagePersons.setPage(page);

    return  pagePersons ;
    }
```